# How to different colours and legend in d3 js donut chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a donut chart here.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/9902/

```
var dataset = {
  apples: [53245],
  oranges: [53245],
  lemons: [53245],
  pears: [53245],
  pineapples: [53245],
};

var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    cwidth = 40;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g");
var path = gs.selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d) { return pie(d); })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", function(d, i, j) { return arc.innerRadius(10+cwidth*j).outerRadius(cwidth*(j+1))(d); });
```

I would like to add my own colour for each ring. I have tried with multiple settings. But couldn't figure out how to add unique colours.

Can someone tell me how to add unique colour and legend to the chart?

thanks

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: using j as the increment: `color(j)`: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/9906/

Comment: @AndrewReid Yes thank you. You have any idea how to add legend for those rings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a legend the process is rather straight-forward.

First, we can append a g to hold the legend:

```
var legend = svg.append('g');
```

D3 selectAll and append statements work with arrays. As you have an object rather than array, we can convert your entries into an array with: `d3.entries(data)`:

Original form:

```
{
   apples:[n],
   oranges:[m],
   ...
}
```

And the result of d3.entires(data):

```
[
   {key: "apples", value:[ [n] ]},
   {key: "oranges", value: [ [m] ]}
   ...
]
```

With this we can append one `g` element for each element that needs to be in the array:

```
var entries = legend.selectAll('g')
 .data(d3.entries(dataset))
 .enter()
 .append('g')
 .attr('transform',function(d,i) { console.log(d);
    return 'translate(30,'+(30+i*30)+')';
 });
```

Note that each g has a slightly different transform. This way the rectangles and text don't need unique transforms, it's done already with the g.

Then we can append rectangles and text to each `g` in the selection `entries`:

```
entries.append('rect')
  .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color(i); })
  .attr('width',20)
  .attr('height',20)
  .attr('x',20)

entries.append('text')
  .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
  .attr('x',50)
  .attr('y',10)
```

*Note: Your `svg` variable represented a selection containing the appended `g` which has a transform appropriate for the donut charts. I've created a new variable to hold this `g` and to which the chart is appended. I've then created an additional `g` (`legend`) that is appended straight to the svg to make the transforms easier to manage.*

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/9911/